# Access Denied Error calling WCF Webservice hosted on IIS

Tags: wcf, web-services

I am calling a WCF webservice hosted on IIS from jQuery on an ASP.Net 4.0 web application. I am getting an "Access Denied" error in jQuery.

This is my method:

```
function LoadName() {
        var body = '{"FirstName": "John","Surname": "Howard"}';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.softlinkwebservices.com:1984/IISWCF/Service1.svc/FullName",
            data: body,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var name = response.FullNameResult;
                alert("Welcome : " + name + "!");

            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert("Error processing request");
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the **service contract** for the service method?? Can you navigate to that service URL in a browser?? What do you see/get returned??

Comment: The "Access is denied" will be somewhere in your IIS logs or log from your service. Did you check those?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to browse to the service in internet explorer and the success response is seen by asking you to download a file that has the resposne in json format.

If you are not able to browse to the service then its an error on the server. Make sure that the service is accessible via the port specified.